# Spring Cloud Kubernetes is not loading secret keys with pattern like xx.yy

Tags: spring, kubernetes, secret-key

I am trying to learn about Spring Cloud Kubernetes for loading secrets and what I have observed is if a property has yml like structure, then it doesn't get loaded in app.

Ex:

```
kind: Secret
metadata:
  name: activemq-secrets
  labels:
    broker: activemq
type: Opaque
data:
  amqusername: bXl1c2VyCg==
  amq.password: MWYyZDFlMmU2N2Rm
```

K8 Manifest

```
  template:
    spec:
      volumes: 
        - name: secretvolume
          secret:
            secretName: activemq-secrets
      containers:
        -
          volumeMounts: 
            - name: secretvolume
              readOnly: true
              mountPath: /etc/secrets/
```

jvm args:

```
-Dspring.cloud.kubernetes.secrets.paths=/etc/secrets/
-Dspring.cloud.kubernetes.secrets.enabled=true
```

Trying to load `@Value("${amqusername}")`works

But when I try to read this property with `@Value("${amq.password}")` I get error with placeholder not found. I have tried printing all spring configs and it doesn't show up. How can I fix this.

Comment: And what if you try to simply inject the values in the Pod environment? Spring should use them automatically

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing the variable name in the secret to amq_password

**Update**:

If you use environment variables rather than system properties, most operating systems disallow period-separated key names, but you can use underscores instead (e.g. SPRING_CONFIG_NAME instead of spring.config.name).

https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.5.6.RELEASE/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html

Comment: Hey thanks for the reply. My requirement is I need to be able to load the property as amq.password so that there is no code change required in app side for loading configs.

Comment: Yes, you will still be able to access the property as amq.password